# Check for validation if Input exceeds the available stocks

Tags: c, validation

Can anybody help me fix the validation of my program

actual output of my program:

choice `1. Import` I input 2 times, my 1st input is `100` 2nd input is `200`

so when viewing the choice `2. Storage` output will be this

```
Year    sets
 1      100
 2      200
```

total of `300` sets of computer in storage

now in choice `3. Sell Order` I input `400` so it will display `Sorry we have No enough Stocks !`

my problem is when viewing my `3. Storage` again all stocks are now empty

```
Year    sets
 1        0
 2        0
```

I am expecting that when my Input exceeds the available stocks it will not continue reduced the stocks in my storage

```
int main(void) {
    int choice = 0;
    int year = 1, i, com;
    int storage[99] = { 0 };

    for (;;) {
        clrscr();

        printf("Year %d\n\n", year);

        printf("1. Import\n");
        printf("2. Storage\n");
        printf("3. Sell Order\n");

        printf("\nchoice: ");

        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 1) { // import
            clrscr();
            printf("Enter sets of computer's imported: ");
            scanf("%d", &storage[year]);
            year++;
        }
        if (choice == 2) { // storage
            clrscr();
            printf("Year    sets\n");

            for (i = 1; i < year; i++) {
                printf("%2d     %4d\n", i, storage[i]);
            }
            getch();
        }
        if (choice == 3) { //order
            printf("Enter Sets of Computer ordered: ");
            scanf("%d", &com);

            for (i = 0; com && i < 99; i++) {
                if (com <= storage[i]) {
                    storage[i] = storage[i] - com;
                    com = 0;
                } else {
                    com = com - storage[i];
                    storage[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            if (com > storage[i]) { // validation
                printf("Sorry we have No enough Stocks !");
                getch();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hpw about validating _before_ subtracting?

Comment: You need to check if `com` is <= the sum of all `storage` before making any changes.  It might make sense to keep the sum of all `storage` in a variable so you always have it on hand, but you could dynamically determine it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wiping the stocks before you have calculated how much stock you have. You want to first add up how much stock you have, check to see if you have enough, THEN wipe the stocks IF you have enough

```
    if (choice == 3) { //order
        printf("Enter Sets of Computer ordered: ");
        scanf("%d", &com);

        for(i=0;i<99;i++)       //calculates the amount of stock you have
        {
            Total_Stock+=storage[i];
        }

        for (i = 0; com && i < 99; i++) {

            if(Total_Stock<com)     //If not enough stock it breaks the loop 
                                    //before subtracting the stock
            {
                printf("Not enough stock.\n");
                break;
            }
            if (com <= storage[i]) {
                storage[i] = storage[i] - com;
                com = 0;
            } else {
                com = com - storage[i];
                storage[i] = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Edited to show an example of possible code, just don't forget to reset the `Total_stock` to zero once that customer has left, otherwise the next time you place an order it will add the left over stock to the pre-existing stock

Comment: when i order 2 times the 2nd order doesn't go "Not enough stock" when it exceed the available stocks

Comment: Did you reset the `Total_stock` to zero before using it again?

Comment: what do you mean reset it ?

Comment: Ok so once the loop has added the stock you have say `Total_stock ==90`. When you then do another order it will add all the stock on top of what is already there, so `Total_stock==(90+however much is left)` To stop this from happening after the order has been done you need to put `Total_stock=0`

Comment: where should i put the Total_stock = 0; ? i ll put it inside the loop

Comment: You need to put it as the last line inside the for loop.